# Adding mouseover effects with d3.tip

Tags: javascript, dom, d3.js, mouseover

Is there a way to add a mousover effect with [d3.tip](http://d3%20tip%20github)

Assuming I have this

```
var tip = d3.tip()
    .attr("class", "d3-tip")
    .html(function(d) { 
        return d.properties.xy
    });


svg.call(tip);
var feature = g.selectAll("circle")
      .data(data.features)
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("r", function (d) {
          d.properties.xy
      })
      .style("fill", "red")
      .attr("fill-opacity", 0.5)
      .on("mouseover", tip.show)
      .on("mouseout", tip.hide);
```

This gives me a tooltip through [d3.tip](http://bl.ocks.org/Caged/6476579). However, what if I would want some effects, like this mouseover does:

```
feature.on("mouseover",function(d) { 
       d3.select(this)
      .transition()
      .ease("elastic")
      .duration(500)
      .attr('r', function (d){ 
          return (10 * d.properties.xy)
      })
      .style("stroke", "black")
      .style("stroke-width", 2)
     });
```

Is there a way to combine these two methods?

See the [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qc2m52zf/3/)
What is missing here is the tooltip with d3.tip on the mouseover, like this [example](http://jrue.github.io/coding/2014/lesson14/) has!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because the tip doesnt know what element to show. So instead of :

```
tip.show
```

Pass it the element you wish to show :

```
tip.show(d)
```

So your function looks like this :

```
 feature.on("mouseover",function(d) { 
            d3.select(this)
            .transition()
            .ease("elastic")
            .duration(1000)
            .attr('r', function(d) {
            return (d.value * 5)
            })
            .style("stroke", "green")
            .style("stroke-width", 2)
            .style("fill", "red")
            tip.show(d)
            });
```

Updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/reko91/qc2m52zf/5/

When you do :

```
.on('mouseover,tip.show)
```

its equivalent to

```
.on('mouseover',function(d){ tip.show(d)});
```

Comment: Haven't implemented the mouseout so youll have to do that one, easy :))

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for sticking with me. Lets delete all the comments below the question?!

Comment: No problem, was busy when you first asked so it took a day or so to reply properly :)